# Кто должен вызывать IDisposable.Dispose() при использовании контейнеров?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

Как я [понял](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4085951/4244707), общее правило гласит, что если в объект передеается что-то из вне, то он не является владельцев данного ресурса и не имеет права вызывать `Dispose()`.

Из этого следует, что контейнер является владельцем того, что он создает.

Допустим, у меня есть какое-то Web API, где на каждый запрос создается `SQL Connection`. Запрос завершается и получается, что соединение не закрывается?

Или DI контейнеры как-то решают подобные задачи и вызывают `Dispose`()?

Видел решения с внедрением фабрик, когда сами объекты создавали экземпляры и тем самым становились владельцами - это истинное решение?

Answer (score 2):

Подобные вопросы решаются тем, что:

1. IoC-библиотека предоставляет возможность работать с набором контейнеров;
2. При удалении контейнера библиотека вызывает `Dispose` у всех disposable-объектов.

В частности для Web API библиотеку настраивают так, чтобы она создавала отдельный контейнер на каждый веб-запрос, и SQL Connection регистрируют так, чтобы он создавался в этом контейнере. При завершении запроса это подключение будет закрыто автоматически.

Например, [вот так это делается в Autofac](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html).

Comment: А как происходит эта "магия" идентификации веб-запроса? Ок, допустим, идентифицировать начало понятно как, а как идентифицировать конец?

Comment: @iluxa1810, Ну вот например тот же Autofac [умеет интегрироваться в MVC-приложения](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html). При этом он автоматом начинает делать много всего, в том числе и встраивается в конвейер обработки запроса. Подозреваю, что там какой-нибудь middleware-обработчик, хотя я  детально не разбирался.